# Cannot narrow down an xpath using mechanize in ruby to extract a table

Tags: ruby, xpath, mechanize

I'm trying to get the data contained after this highlighted td tag:

[image]

(screenshot taken from firefox developer tools)

but I don't understand how I'm going to get there. I tried to use xpath

`page.parser.xpath("//table//tbody//tr//td//ul//form//table//tbody//tr/td")`

but this doesn't work and I assuming it's because I'm not identifying anything? I am not sure how I'm going to identify stuff though, since some of them have no ids or names. So the question is how do I reach this tag.

Comment: "Doesn't work" -- what do you mean? What result did you get, and how does that contrast with what result you expected?

Comment: The only reason to use `A//B` is when you're not sure how many descendants lie between A and B. Otherwise, `//` is inefficient. Also, since you know the name of the form, you can use it: `//form[@name='tF0']/table/tbody/tr[@class='txt2'][1]/td[1]`

Comment: Yeah sorry, "Doesn't work" means it returns an empty string, nothing.

Comment: Also I tried this `page.search('//td[@class="txt2"]')` and It returned 3 tables. So I could use that and select the first one. @LarsH that works as well. I have a new problem now though, irrelevant to this question, the data in the table are generated by javascript

Answer (score 2):

Probably because the `tbody` isn't really there. There's a lot of discussion on SO about that particular issue.

Here's how what I would probably do:

```
td = page.at '#tF0 .txt2'
```